# Visual Studio - exceeds the OS max path limit

Tags: visual-studio

Upon opening a file, unrelated to the package listed in the message, I receive this error

[image]

> Microsoft Visual Studio
> Path: C:\Users\rfa\AppData\Local\Temp\fbfa889b-b871-43e3-86b3-9b6993ad56ed\dotnet-sdk-advertising-temp\microsoft.ios.runtime.iossimulator-arm64.msi.x64\15.4.446-ci.-release-6-0-4xx.446\microsoft.ios.runtime.iossimulator-arm64.msi.x64.15.4.446-ci.-release-6-0-4xx.446.nupkg
> exceeds the OS max path limit. The fully qualified file name must be
> less than 260 characters.